# Acessar dados mais específicos de um objeto

Tags: angularjs

Eu fiz um *`GET`* em uma tabela no meu banco de dados

```
$scope.corretor = {};

$scope.getData = function (){
    $http.get("http://.php")
    .success(function(data){
        $scope.corretor = data;
        console.log($scope.corretor);
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.log(data);
    });
};
$scope.getData();
```

### console.log

```
Object
AGENCIA: ""
BANCO: ""
CELULAR: ""
CEP: ""
CIDADE: ""
COMPLEMENTO: ""
CONTA: ""
CPF: 
DTNASCIMENTO: ""
EMAIL: ""
ENDERECO: ""
ENDERECO_COMERCIAL: ""
ID_CORRETOR: "1"
NOME: "LUIZ FABIO LIMA DE MEDEIROS"
NUMERO_ENDERECO: ""
RG: 
TELEFONE: 
TIPO_CONTA: ""
UF: "PA"
```

Mas o que eu to querendo fazer, é pegar apenas o nome, e jogar dentro de um `ng-options`

Answer (score 4):

Você está atribuindo o retorno.

`$scope.corretor = data;` para a variavel corretor, ou seja agora seu objeto se encontra dentro dessa variavel, no seu controller, você pode acessar a propriedade `NOME` da seguinte forma.

`$scope.corretor.NOME`

no seu html você pode acessar.

`{{corretor.NOME}}`